# Module level sonar analysis in maven Multi Module project

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin, maven-module

While building from my Parent module, the code coverage and sonar anslysis happens fine. Since Sonar does aggregation of code coverage of all sub modules.

However, When I build my sub-module for code coverage, the analysis is not updated back in my Parent project.

**Is there a way to tweak the aggregation both ways, i.e. When Parent build happens or when an individual Module builds independently.** 
I don't want to run the whole parent project everytime, to capture the code coverage analysis in sonar.

My parent pom.xml consists of all sonar,jacoco configurations and other modules inherit them.

```
<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/*ut-jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
```

And each module generates its own moduleX-ut-jacoco.exec.

Comment: Make the sonar analysis on the root project `mvn clean install` and afterwards `mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3:sonar`...

Comment: mvn clean install sonar:sonar   is what I am executing at present.

Comment: I have suggest to make separate calls of it...

Comment: Well, separate or together, didnt make any difference. M still not able to update the metrics while individually building my Module.

Comment: Could this be a limitation of Sonar? Sonar analysis report mentions {"errorMessage":"Validation of project failed:\n  o Component (uuid=AWB8h3BkPLNZb98uiZti, key=com.proj.main:Module1) is not a project\n  o The project \"com.proj.main:MyModule1\" is already defined in SonarQube but as a module of project \"com.proj.main:PARENT\". If you really want to stop directly analysing project \"com.proj.main:PARENT\", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project \"com.proj.main:Module1\"."}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) for guidance. It took a while to understand the behavior but its indeed a learning.

After Module is build with test-case execution using

> mvn clean install

A separate sonr analysis is needed to be run on **parent** project.

> mvn sonar:sonar

This subsequent sonar analysis helped me update coverage and other metrics on Parent porject as well as at Module level.